# Axis-tag does not show helpful information

Tags: discussion, tags

When including the axis tag it just show what I should **not** use it for, but not for what I should actually use it.

[image]

Comment: Yeah fairly sure this description needs to be updated as well, as `apache-axis` is marked as a synonym for `axis`, so isn't the description going back on its self?

Comment: I also could not find the provided link in the description

Comment: Is the tag for Axis as MATLAB-plot axis? If that is the case, then the best thing is to tag it as matlab-figure, or something similar. There is no need of being overly descriptive in tags